# Do AIR apps require the plug-ins (Flash, Acrobat) to run Flash swfs or display PDFs?

Tags: air

This may be a stupid question but I can't seem to find a clear cut answer anywhere. I would like to know:

Can AIR apps display swfs without the Flash player installed on the user's machine?

Can AIR apps display PDFs without Acrobat reader (or some similar PDF viewer)?

From what I can find, the Flash Player is **not** required on the target machine to run swfs from within an AIR app. Is this correct?

And it also seems that you **do** require Acrobat 8 or greater installed on the target machine to view PDFs. Is this correct?

Any help clearing this up would be great.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, an AIR app can load an swf without having the user to install Flash Player plug in or Flash standalone player.
2. No, AIR apps need Acrobat Reader installed. I don't think any other PDF Viewer will do.

You will need to have Adobe Acrobat Reader 8.1 or higher installed as "*AIR applications render PDF content using the HTMLLoader class, the WebKit engine, and the Adobe® Reader® browser plug-in.*"

Regarding the PDF support, check [this link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7eb4.html) for a detailed information.